# Revolute joint with box2d web, wheel not turning around own axis

Tags: javascript, node.js, box2d, box2dweb, box2d-joints

I am trying to use revolute joints in node.js server, but my wheel is not turining around its own axis but around  body.

Here is my code:

```
var joint_def = new b2RevoluteJointDef();
       joint_def.Initialize(this.body , wheel, wheel.GetWorldCenter());

       //after enablemotor , setmotorspeed is used to make the joins rotate , remember!
       joint_def.enableMotor = true;
       joint_def.maxMotorTorque = 100000;

       //this will prevent spinning of wheels when hit by something strong
       joint_def.enableLimit = true;
       joint_def.lowerAngle =  -1 * max_steer_angle;
       joint_def.upperAngle =  max_steer_angle;
       this.joint = world.CreateJoint(joint_def);
```

Then when i press button up i set motor speed like this:

```
this.joint.SetMotorSpeed(10000);
```

And wheel start rotation around the center of the body, but i want to rotate around it's own center.

This are the settings of body and wheel :

```
   'density' : 1.0 ,
    'friction' : 0.0 ,
    'restitution' : 0.2 ,
    'linearDamping' : 0.0 ,
    'angularDamping' : 0.0 ,
    'gravityScale' : 1.0 ,
    'type' : b2Body.b2_dynamicBody
```

What am i doing wrong ? Or maybe i should use different box2d implementation.
I am using box2d from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/box2dweb